# Удаление дубликатов строк в MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Я хочу удалить дубликаты строк из таблицы.

Я попробовал такое решение:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1)
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

На моем 3770k, 16gb ram, сперва tempdb выросла до 65 gb, а спустя сутки выполнения запроса я его прервал. 
В таблице 15 колонок, 200 млн. строк, 42 Гб всего. Есть ли какой-то более быстрый способ для удаления дубликатов или сколько примерно это должно занимать при таком объеме базы?

Могу ли я ускорить процесс сравнивая на дублирование только две колонки?

Comment: Можно сгруппировать по col[1] и удалить по минимальному или максимальному значению поля с айдентити, возможно будет быстрее работать (только если кол-во дублирующихся записей> 1 по каждому значению поля col[1] то скрипт надо будет выполнять несколько раз). Также можно выбрать id которые надо удалить (так как вы сейчас делаете через cte) но вместо удаления вставить id этих записей в какую-нибудь таблицу, посмотреть что выбралось и удалять по чуть чуть. Однако надо быть очень аккуратным, дабы не ошибиться при таком объеме и конечно перед этим снять бекап.

Comment: Какова оценочная доля удаляемых записей? Если велика, то быстрее будет копирование записей, которые должны остаться, во временную таблицу, очистка рабочей таблицы, и возврат оставленных записей.

Comment: PS. Партиционирование и сортировка по одному и тому же полю - вещь абсолютно бессмысленная.

Comment: ну видимо ему все равно какую из двух записей удалять, по этому и сортирует по этому полю

Comment: Побейте на куски, добавив where в запрос и подзапрос, поставив условие на индексированое поле. Для "тренировки" поставтьте в select `top 100`  или `top 1000`

Answer (score 4):

Приведенный запрос противоречит вопросу. Указанный запрос в `CTE` группирует строки по первому столбцу `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1)`. Поэтому запрос удаляет не дубликаты записей, а все записи с идентичным полем `col1` кроме первой. При удалении дубликатов важно в аргументе `PARTITION BY` функции `ROW_NUMBER()` указать перечисление всех столбцов.

Пример для удаления только 1000 первых дубликатов:

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 ORDER BY col1)
        FROM dbo.Table1)
DELETE TOP (1000) FROM cte WHERE RN > 1;
```

Можно выполнять запрос в цикле, удаляя данные маленькими кусками.