# как сделать Update с помощью Select

Tags: sql-server, select, update

у меня есть таблица TICKET и SEGMENTS, в таблице TICKET есть столбец dop_zbor_naprav
где я добавляю число. В таблице SEGMENTS есть столбец BASICFARE где иметься нужное данное (GC10) чтобы обновить столбец dop_zbor_naprav в таблице TICKET.
Я хочу если в таблице SEGMENTS  в столбце BASICFARE было данное "GC10" обновило таблицу TICKET столбец dop_zbor_naprav  на нужное мне число. Ребята помогите с запросом очень сильно прошу.

> типа этого запроса, знаю что этот запрос не работает!
>
> ```
> update TICKET set dop_zbor_naprav='300' where = (select from SEGMENTS where BASICFARE like '%GC10%')
> ```

Comment: `where = ( ...)` а что именно равно из первой таблицы значению, которое возвращает подзапрос ? слева от знака равно должно что то стоять ... И `select from SEGMENTS` быть не может, между словами select и from должно быть указано, что именно вы хотите получить из таблицы.

Comment: И по тексту вопроса вообще ничего не понятно. Возможно потому, что вы путаете понятия строка и столбец. Можно было бы понять что такое столбец dop_zbor_naprav, но строки с каким либо именем в БД быть не может

Comment: я хочу если в таблице SEGMENTS в столбце BASICFARE было значение = GC10 то обновить таблицу TICKET столбца dop_zbor_naprav

Comment: Как связаны между собой таблицы? т.е. - "если в таблице **В**, колонка "В1" содержит значение **х**...то менять все значения в колонке **А1** таблицы **А**? Или в определенных строках?

Comment: в обоих таблицах имеется одинаковые столбцы значение TICKET-BSONUM в SEGMENTS-BSONUM

Comment: @delphi дополните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос схемами таблиц

Comment: Сначала напишите запрос select который бы выбрал данные из обоих таблиц так что бы видеть и старые данные из одной таблицы и то что вы хотите получить из второй таблицы. после этого надо заменить в запросе пару фраз что бы получилось что то вроде `update table1 set x=y from table1 join table2 on ... where ...`

Comment: дополнение 
SELECT BSONUM, BASICFARE FROM SEGMENTS
SELECT dop_zbor_naprav, BSONUM FROM TICKET

Comment: Если вас интерисует как удалить дубли - то так и введите в поиск - удалить дубли - вместо delete поменяете на update. Как - вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607555/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-mssql/658574

Comment: Хотя если ваша задача по русски звучит как "_установить в таблице TICKET столбец dop_zbor_naprav=300 у тех записей, для которых в таблице SEGMENTS есть записи с таким же BSONUM и BASICFARE содержащим GC10_", то достаточно `update TICKET set dop_zbor_naprav='300' where BSONUM IN (select BSONUM from SEGMENTS where BASICFARE like '%GC10%')`. Главное сначала задачу правильно сформулировать ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update t
set dop_zbor_naprav='300' 
FROM TICKET t
    JOIN SEGMENTS s ON t.BSONUM = s.BSONUM
where s.BASICFARE like '%GC10%'
```

Answer (score 1):

вариант от Mike тоже работает, всем спасибо за ответы.

```
UPDATE TICKET SET dop_zbor_naprav='300' 
WHERE BSONUM IN (SELECT BSONUM FROM SEGMENTS
WHERE BASICFARE LIKE'%GC10%')
```